# UIImgePickerView Images taken in landscape stretched when displayed

Tags: ios

In the UIImagePicker the user takes photos, then the photos are saved, and loaded into a tableview, now when the images are taken normally (portrait) they are a perfect size in the image view because this is how I set it. But when the user takes an image with the device in landscape, the image looks skewed and looks very distorted. (See picture)

Top is portrait picture, bottom is landscape

[image: Images]

So does anyone have any suggestions on how this can be done?
Any help would be amazing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The UIImageView stretches images to fit its size. This is what you are seeing. To stop it, you might change the size of the image view, like so:

```
CGRect newFrame = CGRectMake(imageView.frame.origin.x,
                             imageView.frame.origin.y,
                             image.size.width,
                             image.size.height);
imageView.frame = newFrame;
```

Answer (score 2):

If it is taken in Landscape, then you show it another frame with size width > height. Or try using the following code and see if it improves something.

```
imageViewTemp.clipsToBounds = YES; 
imageViewTemp.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
```